# Class Protection Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've taken the information from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
to create a script that will protect a range of cells within sheets from being edited but also excludes areas where a user can enter data. My script looks like this.

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Protect the active sheet except B2:C5, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('2016-07-21 Material Request Form Template');
    var unprotected = sheet.getRange('C9:D9');
    protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);
    // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
    // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
}
```

On the line that reads `var unprotected = sheet.getRange('C9:D9');` this will indeed unlock this range as expected within the protected sheet but I also have other ranges within this document that I'd like to restrict. How can I enter or modify this line so that I can lock out multiple ranges i.e. `C9:D9` and `A12:E12` and `A24:K24`

If I simply copy this line and paste it with a new cell range, it overwrites the previous unprotected range and activates the new line I just pasted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple unprotected ranges you need to pass all of the ranges as the array argument in one call:

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1:A6");
var range2 = sheet.getRange("B1:B6");

protection.setUnprotectedRanges([range1, range2]);
```

Your question seems to switch and you appear to end up asking how to restrict access to multiple ranges, rather than unprotecting them? In order to do this, protect the whole sheet and then unprotect the relevant ranges to achieve what you need.